# Can't clear disk space

Tags: disk-usage

Like the title says, the disk space in my "/" partition is at 97% and that's after deleting GBs worth of files. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

After running `df -Th`, I get the following output:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     787M  3.2M  784M   1% /run
/dev/sda2      ext4      102G   94G  3.1G  97% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs  3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop3     squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1055
/dev/loop1     squashfs   15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/292
/dev/loop2     squashfs  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/88
/dev/loop4     squashfs  2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop5     squashfs   43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop8     squashfs   15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop6     squashfs  4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop7     squashfs   15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop11    squashfs  1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop9     squashfs  1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop10    squashfs  150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/63
/dev/loop12    squashfs   89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7169
/dev/loop13    squashfs  4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop14    squashfs  150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop16    squashfs  8.5M  8.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/81
/dev/loop15    squashfs  8.5M  8.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/77
/dev/loop18    squashfs   89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop17    squashfs   36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop19    squashfs  3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/95
/dev/loop20    squashfs  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/90
/dev/loop21    squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1066
/dev/sdb       ext4      1.8T  1.3T  430G  76% /mnt/Plex
/dev/sdc       ext4      3.6T   89M  3.4T   1% /mnt/Plex2
/dev/sda1      vfat      511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     787M   16K  787M   1% /run/user/128
tmpfs          tmpfs     787M     0  787M   0% /run/user/1000
```

After that, I run `sudo du --max-depth=1 -axh | sort -n` where I get this:

```
0       ./initrd.img
0       ./initrd.img.old
0       ./vmlinuz
0       ./vmlinuz.old
3.8G    ./usr
4.0K    ./cdrom
4.0K    ./lib64
4.0K    ./srv
4.8G    ./var
8.0K    ./media
8.0K    ./mnt
11G     .
12M     ./sbin
13M     ./bin
16K     ./lost+found
16M     ./etc
52K     ./snap
100K    ./tmp
107M    ./boot
203M    ./opt
296K    ./root
560M    ./home
846M    ./lib
```

I've read on a couple of other forums that there may be some files in lsof that haven't been freed up. So I run `sudo lsof | grep deleted` which gets me:

```
mysqld    1128                 mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128                 mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128                 mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128                 mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128                 mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1163            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1163            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1163            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1163            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1163            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1164            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1164            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1164            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1164            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1164            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1165            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1165            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1165            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1165            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1165            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1166            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1166            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1166            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1166            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1166            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1167            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1167            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1167            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1167            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1167            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1168            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1168            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1168            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1168            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1168            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1169            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1169            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1169            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1169            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1169            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1170            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1170            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1170            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1170            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1170            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1171            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1171            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1171            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1171            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1171            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1172            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1172            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1172            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1172            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1172            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1173            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1173            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1173            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1173            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1173            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1174            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1174            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1174            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1174            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1174            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1206            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1206            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1206            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1206            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1206            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1207            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1207            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1207            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1207            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1207            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1208            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1208            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1208            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1208            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1208            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1209            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1209            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1209            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1209            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1209            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1210            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1210            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1210            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1210            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1210            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1211            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1211            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1211            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1211            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1211            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1212            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1212            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1212            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1212            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1212            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1214            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1214            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1214            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1214            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1214            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1215            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1215            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1215            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1215            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1215            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1216            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1216            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1216            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1216            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1216            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1217            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1217            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1217            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1217            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1217            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1218            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1218            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1218            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1218            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1218            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1225            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1225            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1225            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1225            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1225            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1226            mysql    5u      REG                8,2         0    3014658 /tmp/ibbG3efy (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1226            mysql    6u      REG                8,2         0    3014659 /tmp/ib58jSsO (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1226            mysql    7u      REG                8,2         0    3014660 /tmp/ib9uQvG4 (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1226            mysql    8u      REG                8,2         0    3014661 /tmp/ibPox2aB (deleted)
mysqld    1128 1226            mysql   12u      REG                8,2         0    3014662 /tmp/ibl6rfCR (deleted)
apache2   1176                  root    9u      REG                8,2         0    3014663 /tmp/.ZendSem.zhgjQN (deleted)
apache2   1220              www-data    9u      REG                8,2         0    3014663 /tmp/.ZendSem.zhgjQN (deleted)
apache2   1221              www-data    9u      REG                8,2         0    3014663 /tmp/.ZendSem.zhgjQN (deleted)
apache2   1222              www-data    9u      REG                8,2         0    3014663 /tmp/.ZendSem.zhgjQN (deleted)
apache2   1223              www-data    9u      REG                8,2         0    3014663 /tmp/.ZendSem.zhgjQN (deleted)
apache2   1224              www-data    9u      REG                8,2         0    3014663 /tmp/.ZendSem.zhgjQN (deleted)
pulseaudi 1593                   gdm    6u      REG                0,5  67108864      33974 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
null-sink 1593 1598              gdm    6u      REG                0,5  67108864      33974 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
```

I can't seem to find where the missing ~83GB is, unless I'm totally missing something, which is entirely possible.

[image]

GUI version. The top-left shows the main partition with 8.8 GB / 111 GB free. the bottom shows 3.3 GB / 109.1 GB free. Finally, the top-right shows the root directory with 10.5 GB worth of space taken.

Comment: Do `ls -la /` and see if there are any hidden files in your root directory that do not get counted in your first listing.

Comment: There were a few, but `du` says they range anywhere from 0 to maybe 30MB.

Comment: So the largest folder in /var/log/ would be ./journal. I already ran `journalctl --vacuum-time=5d` on it. So the largest remaining log file is from PuTTY.

Comment: Your whole `/var` is reported to be 4.8G, so it can't contain 83G of hidden data.

Comment: I'm saying `/` is hiding 83G of hidden data. `sudo du --max-depth=1 -axh | sort -n` is saying `/` has 11G while `df -Th` is saying `/` has 94G.

Comment: You can try `ncdu -x /` or like [`man ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/man) suggest, in two steps: `ncdu -1xo- / | gzip >export.gz` and later `zcat export.gz | ncdu -f-`. Also to check biggest packages `wajig sizes | tail -30`. Also remove disabled snap packages (from `snap list --all`).

Comment: What files did you delete ? Could it be that some of those files still are open by a program ?

Comment: start by rebooting either the system or the mysql service. The list clearly tells you it is related to mysql... if you delete temp files, a running process will keep them in memory.

Comment: Also look into the mount-points `/mnt/Plex` and `/mntPlex2` while nothing is mounted to them.

Comment: System has been reboot multiple times. `zcat export.gz | ncdu -f-` seems to be giving me the same info that `du` was, as far as saying only ~11 GB is being used on `/`. I guess I'm really confused as to why `df` says there's 94 GB being used in `/` and `du` says only 11 GB is being used. Why is there a 83 GB difference there? I mean, I'm only a casual Ubuntu user, but I feel like there shouldn't be that large of a difference (or one at all).

Comment: @huskermdl: Did you remove the stale snap images as Pablo suggested? What did that do for you? Please report on status, resolution, etc.

Comment: @MalikA.Rumi honestly, I was having such a hard time with it, I just reinstalled Ubuntu. I tried following all the suggestions, but none of them were working.